# How to insert data using parametrized sparql query?

Tags: if-statement, insert, sparql, rdf

I have this insert query:

```
INSERT
{
<http://www.google.com/go/guest> <http://www.google.com/go/hasRelatives> ?state}
WHERE {?state a <http://www.google.com/go#State>.
filter ($state=<http://www.google.com/go/State-USA>)
}
```

If the state is equal to  `<http://www.google.com/go#State-USA>` I would need to insert all the states of type `<http://www.google.com/go#State>`. -Exactly what the SPARQL insert query is doing at the moment.

If not, I would need to insert only the specified state, for example: `<http://www.google.com/go#State-Alabama>`

Like with the below query:

```
INSERT { <http://www.google.com/go/guest> <http://www.google.com/go/hasRelatives> $state }
WHERE {?state a <http://www.google.com/go#State>.
filter ($state!=<http://www.google.com/go/State-USA>)
}
```

How could I write an `if-else` statement inside the insert, to check what the value of ?state is, and then to run the needed insert query.
How could I combine the two queries into only one, with the proper conditions?

The triples:

```
@prefix : <http://www.google.com/go#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

<http://www.google.com/go/State-USA> a :State ;
    rdfs:label "USA" .

<http://www.google.com/go/State-Michigan> a :State ;
    rdfs:label "Michigan" .


<http://www.google.com/go/State-NewYork> a :State ;
    rdfs:label "New York" .


<http://www.google.com/go/State-Alabama> a :State ;
    rdfs:label "Alabama" .
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is in the triple store and what is passed from outside by your client code? Please provide a sample of the existing RDF data and then the expected result after the INSERT - both in Turtle notation, way easier to see structured data instead of a verbalized description

Comment: @UninformedUser I have updated the question with the triples and the two queries.

Comment: thanks - but I think I still don't get it. Your data just contains `rdf:type` triples for the states. But I don't get what else is given. Does the `$state` mean it comes from some external source code as inline string?

Comment: Yes, you can think of $state as <http://www.google.com/go/State-Alabama> for example. Or <http://www.google.com/go/State-USA>. It comes from external source